# Is there a certain depth before python see's a number a zero?

Tags: python

Long story short, I'm creating a graph using networkx and the lower the weights between nodes(edges) the better.

My problem is pagerank doesn't like getting a weight of zero and gives me an error.  So I was thinking is there a number that is essentially zero in python but not exactly zero. Something like 0.0000000000001?

or if my approach is really horrible(which I suspect it might) is there another way to deal with this?  Pagerank recussivily gets a score and then normalizes it against the entire dataset so scores tend to be very low as dataset gets larger(think 1/billion nodes).

Comment: This isn't a python issue as a *maths* problem.

Comment: There isn't much code to post, I simply create some nodes, then some edges to other nodes and get the error when the weight of the edge is 0.0.

Comment: @Arafangion I know its impossible to divide by zero but I'm trying to figure out a way python can help me as close to zero as possible.

Comment: Usually, if you get a divide by zero error from an expression that you expect a finite value, that's because the numerator and the denominator both approach zero. In such cases, it's a much more robust solution to analytically take the limit of that expression as the denominator goes to zero, and use it when the denominator is too small.

Comment: I wanted to just say that this is one of the few SO questions that has seriously brought up a perplexing question for me out of no where. So... +10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [`sys.float_info.min`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.float_info), the value of the minimum positive normalized float. On my system, this is `2.2250738585072014e-308`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Is this limitation based on systems themselves? or is there a universal number(or common minimum)? I think its safer to use your approach than a static number but I'm just curious.

Comment: It is system dependent, but for me its the same across Snow Leopard, Ubuntu, and Windows 7 platforms that I was just able to try

Comment: Its based on the machine representation - internally, a float is represented by something equivalent to 1*2^x.  The -308 is the base-10 equivalent of the most negative x possible on your system.  In general, this should be based on the bit size(?) of your computer/python version (32 bit or 64 bit).

Comment: Strangely, even though this is reported as the min float number...check this out:  `2.2250738585072014e-308 + 2.2250738585072014e-308 == 4.4501477170144028e-308` yet `2.2250738585072014e-324 + 2.2250738585072014e-324 == 0.0`

Comment: @Lostsoul I just tried this on a couple of machines where `sys` didn't have a `float_info` attribute. Maybe something to be careful about!

Comment: @jdi: Why is that strange? `2.2250738585072014e-324` is ten quadrillion times smaller than the min number, so it's effectively zero. You've just written that `0.0 + 0.0 == 0.0`.

Comment: Well what I was trying to say was that I found it strange that the min number doesnt really seem to be the min number since you can use `2.2250738585072014e-324` and still have it not equal 0.0

Comment: @jdi But `2.2250738585072014e-324` **does** equal 0.0. The fact that the compiler doesn't raise a `SyntaxError` is beside the point. At the stage where an actual object is created to represent that number, the bytes used inside that object to represent the value are the same ones used for an object created from `0.0`. Try entering the values by themselves at the REPL (instead of adding them to themselves).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I apoligize for the typo I made on the previous comment. What I was confused about is why actually the value `1.9762625833649862e-323` evals as being LESS than the sys.float_info.min yet GREATER than 0.0. It seems to me that it means a number can be represented less than what sys.float_info.min suggests. If the OPs question was regarding a problem where a number that evals to 0.0 would raise an exception, then `1.9762625833649862e-323` would not yet its smaller than the reported min.

Comment: @jdi: `sys.float_info.min` is the minimum positive *normalized* float. `1.9762625833649862e-323` aka `2e-323` is not normalized.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> 1e-324
0.0
>>> 1e-323
9.8813129168249309e-324
```

**Some interesting tests**

```
>>> 1e-307 < sys.float_info.min
False
>>> 1e-307 > sys.float_info.min
True
>>> 1e-323 < sys.float_info.min
True
>>> 1e-323 + 1e-323
1.9762625833649862e-323
>>> 1e-324 + 1e-324
0.0
```

*Update for @Kari's comment*

Im curious why this is True

```
>>> 0.0 < 1e-323 < sys.float_info.min
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the absolute number.  It works the same on my system also.  +1

Comment: Seems like you could technically represent smaller numbers than sys.float_info.min though

Comment: Yes; those are 'denormalized' values.